# Not Getting Expected Result in Negative Case with *ngIf in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

In my Angular2 app I am printing to the view some data in a table layout. One section of our data is an array of flags. Right now I'm successfully using a combination of `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` to print values to the view when those values exist. This is all working as expected with this code:

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let status of record.status"> 
        <td *ngFor="let flag of status.flags"> 
            <span *ngIf="flag.flag" class="standard-flag">
                 {{flag?.flag}} 
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!flag.flag" class="zero-flags">
                No Flags
            </span>
        </td>  
    </ng-container>
```

Now, in the case where there is no data (i.e., empty arrays) I'd like to simply print "No Flags" to the screen -- see above. As far as I know, there is no "else" functionality prior to Angular 4 (correct me if I'm wrong). So what I need to do is use an `*ngIf` to evaluate when this is the case and print 'No Flags' to the screen accordingly.

This is proving peculiarly difficult, and I'm not sure why. I've stared at the screen for too long, and have tried numerous combinations, all to no avail.

To handle the case where there is no value in "flags", I've tried what I have now:

```
<span *ngIf="!flag.flag" class="zero-flags">
```

As well as:

```
<span *ngIf="flag.flag ===''" class="zero-flags">
```

I don't get errors, I just either get the correct value printed to the view, or, if there is no value, nothing appears at all (when what should appear is "No Flags"). What am I missing here? How could I handle this to get the desired result? Basically, I want "No Flags" to print to the view in the case where "flags" is an empty array for all 3 objects within the "status" array.

For reference, the data looks like this:

```
"status": [
    {
        "reference": "gold",
        "flags": []
    },
    {
        "reference": "silver",
        "flags": []
    },
    {
        "reference": "bronze",
        "flags": [
            {
                "flag": "Not Available",
                "flagType": "normal"
            }
    }
],
```

Comment: If you open it in the inspector, is the div there or commented out?

Comment: It's commented out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no flags in `status.flags` you will never hit the statement that prints "No flags". You can't iterate an empty array. Use an `*ngIf` to check if there are any flags in `status.flags` first. If not print "No flags".

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let status of record.status">
    <div *ngIf="status.flags.length > 0">
        <td *ngFor="let flag of status.flags"> 
            <span *ngIf="flag.flag" class="standard-flag">
                {{flag?.flag}} 
            </span>
        </td>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="status.flags.length < 1">
        <td>
            <span *ngIf="!flag.flag" class="zero-flags">
                No Flags
            </span>
        </td>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Right answer, thanks. The answer above you had identified the same issue just before you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Youre welcome, but look at the time for our answers, i answered 3 minutes earlier... :)

Comment: Right you are. Marked yours as correct, accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`*ngFor` will only run if there is data in the array.  Otherwise, everything inside it is ignored, so your "No Flags" markup is never being read at all.

Try moving it outside of the `*ngfor` and writing it like this:

```
<td *ngIf="!status.flags.length">
    <span class="zero-flags">
        No Flags
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Ah, I think you're onto something here. That best explains what I'm seeing. Will give this a try, thanks.

Comment: This was the issue, thanks. Didn't realize this about *ngFor. Good to know. :)

Comment: Both you and the other commenter pointed out the correct issue. Just realized his was posted just before, so I marked that as the correct answer. But thanks to both of you for the troubleshooting help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span *ngIf="flag.flag !== '';else noFlag" class="standard-flag">
    {{flag?.flag}} 
</span>

<ng-template #noFlag>No Flags</ng-template>
```

Comment: Does this work in Angular 2? Or is this only valid for Angular 4+?

Comment: Yup. Thought so. Not an option in Angular 2.

Answer (score -1):

Print  'flag.flag' and see its value.If you look at below samples.Any values such as '',null,undefined can also make your section vanish

```
 <span *ngIf="''" class="zero-flags">
                    No Flags -- wont work
                </span> 
                <span *ngIf="null" class="zero-flags">
                    No Flags  -- wont work
                </span> 
                <span *ngIf="undefined" class="zero-flags">
                    No Flags  -- wont work
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="false" class="zero-flags">
                    No Flags 
                </span> 
                <span *ngIf="true" class="zero-flags">
                    No Flags
                </span>
```